# Can't access bios setup, just grub rescue

Tags: windows, windows-8, bios, grub, grub2

My laptop bluescreened last night,and when I turned it on this morning I got the grub rescue prompt.  I dual boot Windows 8.0 and Ubuntu.  When the bios splash screen comes up, it lists all my HDDs, ram, etc, and then immediately goes to grub rescue without prompting me to press Delete or F12 to enter setup/boot list.  I stuck in a flash drive with a linux live cd on it (that works fine) and while the bios lists it, it still boots to grub rescue.  Keyboard works fine in grub rescue, so that's not the issue.  I tried the 'take out battery and hold power button' trick with no luck.  Grub lists all my HDDs correctly, although I can't confirm that all the partitions are showing up as I don't remember my partition scheme.  At this point I'd be fine with just removing grub as it's being a pain, but I can't even boot the live cd or windows setup drive

EDIT: by removing different combinations of drives I have managed to get it to boot to grub, and via grub command line I can get it to boot usb linux.  I tried reinstalling grub but that didn't help.  Selecting windows from the grub menu says BOOTMGR not found, even though I can see it on the hdd in usb linux.  Attempting to boot windows (or my windows usb installer) from the grub command line just gives a black screen with a blinking cursor in the corner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had something similar. What I did was unplugging the drive, insert windows cd, booted from the CD and then re-plug the drive.
Or if the drive with grub doesn't have anything too important that cannot be extracted format the drive.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, good idea! Drives are a pain to get to though :(

Comment: @zacaj Let me know if it worked 

Comment: After removing all HDDs I was able to get it to boot the linux live drive, but of course I can't fix my HDDs from there because they're all unplugged.  Even after rebooting from that, I still can't access my bios, and it seems that every single HDD has a higher priority than my usb drive

Comment: @zacaj Can you enter BIOS when all drives are unplugged? And when you're suppose to select a drive to boot from plug in the drive you want.

Comment: Even with all drives unplugged, I can't enter the bios.  It just says 'no devices found, insert the primary drive and press a key to boot'

Comment: @zacaj That's because you need to press the key that will enter BIOS. When you turn up the computer there's a screen that shows the buttons, usually del/f12/f9. Before you get to "no devices found" press that key. Reboot if you failed.

Comment: Sorry, should have specified, I was pressing the right key and it ignored me. Also it never tells me to press a key at any point like it normally does (but I know the keys for this computer from memory)

Comment: Strange, I need to go for the next couple of hours. Your last resort will be to reset your bios. You can do it with the hardware but it will require to re-enter your windows key and probably cause unexpected problems. You can do it by removing the battery or ground the bios chip. Search for how to do it and the consequences online. DO IT ONLY WHEN YOU HAVE NO OTHER CHOICE. Good luck.

Comment: (see edit for update, fyi).  Haven't been able to find how to reset my bios yet

Comment: found the battery and reset the bios, now I can finally get into bios setup, edit boot priority, and access windows usb installer.  Thanks for the tip!

now just to actually get windows to boot again...

Comment: @zacaj Glad to help!